# How to handle locked files through the Box API

Tags: box-api

I have a customer who has a locked file in their Box Account.  The behaviour I would expect for a locked file is that I should be able to download it, but not modify it.  Instead it appears I am not able to download the file or view the versions for it.  All the requests below work correctly on an adjacent unlocked file in the same users folder.

Is this the expected behaviour?  What is the right way to handle locked files through the API?

**Info Request:(works)**

```
curl 'https://api.box.com/2.0/files/<id>' -H 'Authorization: <auth_info>'
```

Response:

```
{"type":"file","id":"<id>","sequence_id":"0"...}
```

**Versions Request:(400 error)**

```
curl 'https://api.box.com/2.0/files/<id>/versions' -H 'Authorization: <auth_info>'
```

Response:

```
{"type":"error","status":400,"code":"bad_request","help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Bad Request","request_id":"2054523152510ff775496b6"}
```

**Download Request:(403 error)**

```
curl 'https://api.box.com/2.0/files/<id>/content' -H 'Authorization: <auth_info>'
```

Response:

```
{"type":"error","status":403,"code":"access_denied_item_locked","help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Access denied - item locked","request_id":"903163092510ff81985559"}
```